# Angular 2 - Calling function from DOM element's directive

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have some dynamically created elements with a directive. I have to call a function from element's directive in some cases. If I were created this elements statically, I would use `@ViewChild('myElement') myElement` in the component and something like:

```
<div #myelement myDirective>...</div>
```

in the HTML. However I couldn't to that because I creating this elements dynamically (I don't know such a method to give `#myelement1`, `#myelement2`, ... tags dynamically). My idea was getting the elements with `document.getElementById()` but I couldn't access the directive from native DOM element.

Any idea how to access the directives of these elements without using `@VievChild()`?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by accessing element's directive?

Comment: I should call a function from that directive. It has an inner logic that I can't change from outside.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this :

html:

```
<div mask="mask1"></div>
<div mask="mask2"></div>
```

ts:

```
import { Directive, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[mask]' 
})
export class Mask {
  @Input() mask: string;

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.mask);
  }

  getMask(){
    return this.mask;
  }
}

import { Component, ViewChildren,QueryList } from '@angular/core';
//...
export class AppComponent {
  public user;

  @ViewChildren(Mask) masks: QueryList<Mask>;
  constructor( ){}

 ngAfterViewInit(){

    this.masks.forEach((mask)=>{
       console.log(mask.getMask());
    })
   // not sure of this
   this.masks.changes.subscribe((mask)=>{
       console.log(mask.getMask());
    })
 }

}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but will the `@ViewChildren(Mask) masks: QueryList<Mask>;` get all the `Mask`s each time if new elements created further?

Comment: `this.masks.changes` is undefined, and `masks` selects only one of the directives, not all of them.